# HTML/CSS/JS - Issues creating two vertical sections

Tags: html, javascript, css

I'm trying to create two vertical sections for a web page I'm making (using netlify connected to my github repo) and I cannot seem to set up two vertical sections. I'd ideally like for the left-most pane to cover one-third of the screen while the right-hand pane covers two-thirds. Here's the code I have so far, but it seems to fail:

For the .js file:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Header from '@components/Header'
import Footer from '@components/Footer'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Ayy Lmao</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/MyLOGO.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <Header title="Under construction!" />
    
        //<p className="description">
          //For all business inquiries, please call 911
        //</p>
    
    <style>
    .indent-1 {float: left;}
    .indent-1 section {width: 30%; float: left;}
</style>

<section class="indent-1">
    <!-- Section 1 --> 
    <section>
        <div>Some content 1</div>
        <div>Some more 1</div>
    </section>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section>
        <div>Some content 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
    </section>
</section>  
    
      </main>
    
      

      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

For the CSS file:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell,
    Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  padding: 5rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

code {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Courier New, monospace;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, but I would appreciate any help!

Comment: As always, don't use float for alignign purpose. `float` is for flaoting an element within a text-block. For aligning items next to each other you should use `Flexbox` or alternativly `CSS-Grid`. Note that declaratiosn within a `<style>`-tag have a higher specificity then CSS and as such overwrite CSS. Also it is invalid to place the `<style>` tag outside of the head-element as the scope-attribute has been deprecated since 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the 2 `<section>` elements should always have a ⅓/⅔ split, I would recommend using the CSS Flexbox system.

Here is a simplified example:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

section {
  height: 300px;
}

.section-1 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: calc(100% /3);
}

.section-2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: calc((100% /3) * 2);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="section-1"></section>
  <section class="section-2"></section>
</body>
```

Looking at your code, I would simply say its pretty complex for achieving a fairly simple behaviour. Always look for the most straight-forward solution.

For page layouts, I pretty much live and die by Flexbox, but I know others that feel the same way about the CSS Grid system.

[Here is a good guide on the Flexbox system.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Also I would try and avoid reliance on libraries like bootstrap for these sorts  of things, as pure CSS (learned well), can be a far more powerful tool.

Hope this helps.